# Css override for equal specificity

Tags: css

I'm aware that the browser applies styles in a component based on the specificity selector in css, some might not override because of the specificity they have, i.e they not have the same "value" for the browser.

In cases as the following image where the specificity is the same and it was supposed to override the top property, how can we override any property with another class with the same specificity, i.e fix this problem?

[image: Css specificity]

Comment: If the specificity is truly equal, then the last rule applied will win. Re-order your rules so that it comes last. Just avoid `!important` at all costs.

Comment: You can always add specificity, even something "trivial" like div#Timeline or w/e. Even use inline style if you want to override 1 rule

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: If the above comments don't help, can you show the HTML? In particular, show us if the classes timeline-wrapper and full-screen are on the same element.

Comment: Need more information. Please include markup where these classes are applied.